# CAN identifier message sync issue

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, signals, can-bus

I am struggling with a CAN code. with Arduino I am sending two signals with 2 different identifiers and my code checks the identifier id and then interprets the message as eithr state-of-charge or a Voltage message. The code works fine with a single SOC or volt message.
The problem im getting is that when there are multiple message, the code reads the identifier once and then reads all messages given. This means, it reads id 0x140, then reads all signals even the ones that are associated with other ids. 
I don't know if its problem with my code or have to activate some flags or something.

```
//WORKS FINE FOR A SINGLE CAN MESSAGE, BUT HAVE ID - MESSAGE SYN ISSUES 
//WITH MULTIPLE MESSAGES//
    #include "pin_info.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Time.h>
    #include <SPI.h> //for CAN
    #include "mcp_can.h"
    //#include "canLib.h"
    #include "FreeMono9pt7b.h"

    const int spiCSPin = 3;
    MCP_CAN CAN(spiCSPin);

    unsigned char len = 0;
    unsigned char temp_buf[8];
    unsigned char soc_buf[8]={0};
    unsigned char volt_buf[8]={0};
    unsigned char soc_mean[2], soc_min[2], soc_max[2] ={0,0};
    float s_mean, s_min, s_max;
    unsigned char volt_mean[2], volt_max[2], volt_min[2]= {0,0};
    float v_mean, v_min, v_max;
    int len_= sizeof(soc_mean);    
    const char Message[]= "CAN Message: " ;
    const char Name[]= "foxBMS";
    //enum type{soc,SOC, volt, VOLT};

    void setup()
    {
        /*FOR CAN*/
        Serial.begin(115200);
        pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
        while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_500KBPS))
        {
        Serial.println("CAN BUS Init Failed");
        delay(100);
        }
        Serial.println("CAN BUS  Init OK!");

        /* set mask, set both the mask to 0x3ff*/
        CAN.init_Mask(0, 0, 0x3ff);    // there are 2 mask in mcp2515, you need to set both of them
        CAN.init_Mask(1, 0, 0x3ff);

        /*set filter, we can receive id from 0x140 & 0x170 */
        CAN.init_Filt(0, 0, 0x140);                          // there are 6 filter in mcp2515
        CAN.init_Filt(1, 0, 0x170);                          // there are 6 filter in mcp2515
   }

void loop()
    {
       if(CAN_MSGAVAIL == CAN.checkReceive())
    {
     unsigned long canId = CAN.getCanId();
     CAN.readMsgBuf(&len, temp_buf);

     assign(temp_buf,canId);
     serialDisplay(canId);
     //CAN.checkClearRxStatus(temp_buf);
     CAN.clearBufferTransmitIfFlags(); 
    }

    else
       { Serial.print("No message received \n");

       }
      }


    void assign(unsigned char buf[], unsigned long id)
    {
      if(id==0x00)
      {}
      else if(id==0x140)
      {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
          {
            if (i<2)
              soc_mean[i]= buf[i];
            else if (i<4 && i>=2)
              soc_min[i-2]= buf[i];
            else if (i<6 && i>=4)
              soc_max[i-4]= buf[i];
           }
     }
      else if(id==0x170)
      {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
          {
            if (i<2)
              volt_mean[i]= buf[i];
            else if (i<4 && i>=2)
              volt_min[i-2]= buf[i];
            else if (i<6 && i>=4)
              volt_max[i-4]= buf[i];
           }
       }
     }


    void serialDisplay(unsigned long id)
    {
        Serial.println("-----------------------------");
        Serial.print("Data from ID: ");
        Serial.print(id,HEX); Serial.println("- CAN0_MSG");
       for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
         {
          Serial.print(temp_buf[i], HEX); Serial.print("\t");
          }
        Serial.print("\n"); 
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your code and fix the indention.

Comment: Anyway, the bug is almost certainly array out of bounds access. Single step through the assign function in your debugger, watch `i` and the various arrays.

Comment: Reason is you are printing `temp_buf`. If ID is 0x140 then you are storing data in SOC_xxx and for 0x170, data is in volt_xxx but you are printing temp_buf. Means, your code prints every message received. So your code is working exactly like it should.